# PHPStorm: Jump to matching brace/bracket/parentheses like in SublimeText

Tags: phpstorm, sublimetext

In PHPStorm and SublimeText there are hotkeys for going to the matching brace/bracket/parentheses.

In SublimeText this is very intuitive: When directly at said character, you can jump to the matching character and from there you can jump back (symmetrically). When not directly at a brace/bracket/parentheses, you will move to the closest one.

In PHPStorm this is not at all intuitive. The matching is not symmetrical and sometimes no matched character is found at all, even though it is highlighted in the editor.

Is there any way to make PHPStorm behave like SublimeText in this regard?

Here are two simple examples that show the problem (cursor is marked with `C1`, `C2` etc.):

**Example 1**

```
$x = C1[C2
    'foo', 'bar',C3
C4]C5;
```

Cursor at `C1`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C5`
- PHPStorm: Cursor does not move

Cursor at `C2`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C4`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C1`

Cursor at `C3`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C4`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C1`

Cursor at `C4`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C2`
- PHPStorm: Cursor does not move

Cursor at `C5`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C1`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C4`

**Example 2**

```
if C1(C2 'foo' ===C3 'bar' C4)C5 C6{C7

C8}C9
```

Cursor at `C1`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C5`
- PHPStorm: Cursor does not move

Cursor at `C2`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C4`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C1`

Cursor at `C3`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C4`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C1`

Cursor at `C4`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C2`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C1`

Cursor at `C5`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C1`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C4`

Cursor at `C6`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C9`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C9`

Cursor at `C7`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C8`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C9`

Cursor at `C8`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C7`
- PHPStorm: Cursor goes to `C7`

Cursor at `C9`

- SublimeText: Cursor goes to `C6`
- PHPStorm: Cursor does not move

Edit: A very similar behaviour is described at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12068 which would already be an improvement.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12068

Comment: @LazyOne The description in the IDEA is not exactly like the SublimeText behavior (when after a brace/bracket/parentheses, you jump to before the matching character, when before it you jump after the matching character), but still would be an improvement to the current functionality. I'll link it in the problem description.

Comment: The point of that ticket is: such functionality is simply not yet implemented/not working in general; if that would work only then we could speak about "matching Sublime Text behaviour exactly" case .

Comment: @LazyOne I understand that. I have already seen the IDEA before while searching the web for any solution, but I had the hope that there exists some kind of plugin for PHPStorm that can emulate the functionality. Or that someone knows how to write such a plugin. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDEA at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12068 (as suggested by LazyOne) was changed to state "fixed" at 25 Sep 2015. It seems to be integrated since PHPStorm 10.0. Feels good now :)